# np.savetxt style nicely tabulated output for pandas DataFrame.to_csv

Tags: csv, numpy, pandas

I pulled off some hair but still cannot obtain a nicely tabulated output.

In a word, I would like the file saved by the `.to_csv()` method to look like this:

```
               K0         V0     dK_dT         a             b
value  237.496942  82.845746 -0.037012  0.000006  1.359708e-08
std      2.094088   0.012948  0.004415  0.000001  1.550236e-09
```

But with what I can do, `print result.to_csv(float_format='%10.2g', sep=' ')` gives me:

```
 K0 V0 dK_dT a b
value "   2.4e+02" "        83" "    -0.037" "   5.8e-06" "   1.4e-08"
std "       2.1" "     0.013" "    0.0044" "     1e-06" "   1.6e-09"
```

1. the header does not automatically align.
2. the quotes disrupt the equal width flow.

I tried setting `quoting` to some `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` which are essentially ints but with no luck. As far as I know, NumPy can easily do this with `savetxt(format='%10.2g')`.

Anything I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `to_csv()`, you could use [`to_string()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#writing-a-formatted-string).  For example,

```
In [80]: df
Out[80]: 
            A         B             C
a  123.456789  0.702380  7.071752e-08
b    1.230000  0.323674  6.075386e-08
c    0.012300  0.621974  7.918532e-08
d    0.000000  0.818291  5.480469e-08
e   -9.876543  0.117978  9.831873e-08

In [81]: txt = df.to_string()

In [82]: print txt
            A         B             C
a  123.456789  0.702380  7.071752e-08
b    1.230000  0.323674  6.075386e-08
c    0.012300  0.621974  7.918532e-08
d    0.000000  0.818291  5.480469e-08
e   -9.876543  0.117978  9.831873e-08
```

You can then write `txt` to a file.

Comment: Awesome! I knew there should be a most straightforward way. But why doesn't this method accept a simple string for `float_format`, but it has to be a function? Just like to_csv()?

Comment: I don't know.  That confused me, too.  Having the same argument name in similar functions behave differently is an unfortunate API design choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a silly trick: use ASCII BEL (bell) as your quote character.  At least on my system this prints no quotes at all:

```
result.to_csv(float_format='%10.2g', sep=' ', index=False, quotechar='\a')
```

Or use a dummy character and replace it at the end:

```
ss = result.to_csv(float_format='%10.2g', sep=' ', index=False, quotechar='^')
print ss.replace('^', '')
```